# Haskell Strange Operator

Tags: haskell

For an assignment for my functional programming class I am working on an exercise on trees. And more specifically on Rose trees. In the framework that we got the data type 'Rose' is already defined, but it has an operator :>. I searched it on hoogle and it said that it's the rightmost element of a sequence and the rest of the sequence. (Part of the framework below)

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Exercise 1

root :: Rose a -> a
root = undefined

children :: Rose a -> [Rose a]
children = undefined
```

I by no means need you guys to tell me how the root and children function should be made. But if you guys could give me some tips as to how to read the 'data Rose a' line or maybe show me how a rose tree would be build up. These things would be a really big help as I enjoy doing the excercises.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

t's very similar to the definition of a list:

- `(:>)` is a bit like `(:)`
- `data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]` tells you, that you can get a `t :: Rose a`

  - with an element `x :: a`
  - and children `rs :: [Rose a]`
  - by `t = x :> rs`

of course you can get back the elements like this too:

```
root (x :> rs) = ...
```

I hope you get the rest by yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks, real big help. Yeah I got the root and children functions down now.

Answer (score 9):

The `:>` operator is actually a data constructor.  It would be equivalent to define the type as

```
data Rose a = Node a [Rose a]
```

Where `(:>) = Node`.  So with this alternate definition you would have

```
root :: Rose a -> a
root (Node a subnodes) = a
```

Substituting for the actual constructor `:>` you would have

```
root ((:>) a subnodes) = a
```

Which can also be written as

```
root (a :> subnodes) = a
```

As @Carsten says it's just like the list constructor `:`, just specialized for the `Rose` data type.

Answer (score 7):

The `:>` operator has no predefined meaning. It is *introduced by* your Rose definition, just like the identifier `Rose` is. In Haskell you can define your own operators, this is one of them.

This particular operator is a data constructor, which can be determined by the first character. Data constructors start with a colon. Operators that don't start with a colon are normal functions.

It works exactly like any other data constructor, the only difference is that it's written in infix form, like `:`. In this program, it can be read as "attached to".

Since everyone can use it in their own program for any purpose, it is pointless to google it.